# Docker: Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: macos, apache, docker, docker-compose

After update my Mac to the *Catalina*, unfortunately, I got Error:

`ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/Users/maciejtrzcinski/Sites/docker/openinvest/config/apache/.htaccess\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a088def6294f3c190633026f8d28b68bc6a6eb5cbca33f2dcf7272d716a54ba5/merged\\\" at \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a088def6294f3c190633026f8d28b68bc6a6eb5cbca33f2dcf7272d716a54ba5/merged/var/www/html/.htaccess\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

YML file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-php7.2
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./log/apache2:/var/log/apache2
      - ./config/apache/.apache:/var/www/html/.apache
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    ports:
      - 80:80
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
```

I'm trying with `- ./config/apache/:/var/www/html/`, but this also doesn't work.
Anybody know maybe where is it the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the old container and added a new one and works.

1. `docker-machine remove [old]`
2. `docker-machine create [new]`
3. `eval $(docker-machine env [new])`
4. `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was working on a **Rails** application on **Ubuntu 18.04**. I have the application setup with a `Dockerfile` and with `docker-compose.yml`.

**Here's the error I was getting**:

I had previously built the image(s) using `docker-compose build`, so I no longer run the `docker-compose build` again, however, when I run the command `docker-compose up` to start up the container(s), I get this error:

> ERROR: for mailing_list_app_1  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh\": stat ./entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
>
> ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh\": stat ./entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

The issue was that I moved and renamed the file `/entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh` to `docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh`.

So when I run the command `docker-compose up` to start up the container(s) it fails because it can no longer find the `/entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh` file.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Rebuild the image for the project by running the command. This copies the **new** file (`docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh`) into the new image, and removes the link to the **old** file (`/entrypoints/rails-entrypoint.sh`):

```
docker-compose build
```

And then start up the container again using the newly built image:

```
docker-compose up
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**